# Do Light-clients still work after merge?

Tags: nodes, consensus, light-clients, the-merge

After the merge, my light client suddenly stopped working. Is there a way to fix this/ do I need to run a consensus node?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syncing functionality of the geth light node does not currently (Nov 2022) work post-merge, because the historical execution layer blocks are no longer sufficient to light-verify the chain. There is an open PR to add support for standalone beacon chain light syncing in geth here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/25901

This is only the first step to restoring the expected functionality of the geth light node. I expect it won't be until early 2023 when the expected functionality is restored.

Comment: hey there, could you please update your answer for the end of 2023? tia

Answer (score 0):

For Geth, you can specify “—-syncmode light”, or you can try Erigon. You need to run a consensus node only if you’re validating.

Comment: Ah ok. I am asking because right at the merge my geth light-client failed and I can't get synced since then....

Comment: @Markusbug have you solved the issue maybe?

Comment: @IvanAracki No, but there are two Light Client Proxy alternatives now: github.com/a16z/helios by a16z and the https://github.com/status-im/nimbus-eth1/tree/master/lc_proxy by nimbus

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [helios](https://github.com/a16z/helios) it's a light client made by a16z that should work post merge.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Helios is a light client proxy, not a fully sovereign light client, and requires a third-party RPC to function. The geth light client (pre-merge) did not need any RPC.