# how connect in rpc file go ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, rpc

i try much more time to connect rpc my geth, i got it cant run ,,syncmode light,, okay but can i used --syncmode fast? or how i connect in my rpc file , to be read from the geth side, also see the config.ini file, i am worked in ganache and working well my tools but cant run in geth my tools, please someone give me full comand which comand can i runing and what can i past in my config ini file, i mean local host and port

Comment: Have you updated Geth? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134234/what-version-of-geth-do-i-need-for-the-merge

Comment: `Geth
Version: 1.10.26-stable
Git Commit: e5eb32acee19cc9fca6a03b102*************
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.18.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go`

Comment: So your tools work with Ganache but now stopped working with Geth? Assuming Geth is all synced and working normally, the default localhost 8545 hasn't changed... You might need to mention what tool is no longer working? I am confused if your issue is with tools or running Geth.

Comment: my tool worked perfectly with the ganache, now i want to test on goerli on sepolia and also on mainnet, my tool config.ini file include rpc = http:localhost:8545 this working nice in ganache,  now i need to run a comand that will work the same way in geth, i can say i dont know what command to use to connect my tool rpc,

Comment: Is the question how to run Geth on a testnet? If tool is not writing to the chain, you can try on mainnet and http:localhost:8545 is correct and hasn't changed. Is your Geth Version: 1.10.26 running on mainnet?

Comment: For testnet, I just saw https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135093/post-merge-network-but-no-beacon-client-seen-please-launch-one-to-follow-the-c

Comment: my question, how connect my tool in geth, testnet also mainnet, yes runing well with syncmode light, i cant imagine if working ligth client but working i think eth team solve light ocnnection problem

Comment: when i runing geth i see url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551 also some endpoint and can i use 8545 port?

Comment: when i try to connect rpc in my tool and runing got error IPC / RPC error: {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'error': {'code': -32000, 'message': 'getDeleteStateObject (**********************************) error: no suitable peers available'}}

Comment: It is not clear to me if this question is about light client. Either way, you've provided more information and it might help someone else answer. I don't know and only other suggestion if you don't want to run usual Geth node with the links I've provided above, is to try the Geth Discord https://discord.com/invite/nthXNEv If you get an answer, please write answer here. (I will try to edit it if help is needed.)

Comment: Currently, you can't use a Geth light client: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135812/do-light-clients-still-work-after-merge

Comment: which mode can i use like light node?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Normally all these comments would be moved to chat, but that might unlink the "Linked" questions on the sidebar, and with them you already have all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the geth json-rpc via ipc using the following command:

```
geth attach /path/to/geth.ipc
```